# How is the iterator not invalid after deletion with a list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl

If I understand [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation) table correctly, a `std::list` still has a valid iterator after removal of an item from it.  So that in my mind means that this is valid code:

```
#include <list>


int main()
{
    std::list<int> list;
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        list.push_back(x);
    }
    for (auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (*iter % 2)
        {
            list.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the every even item is deleted, we can still use the iterator to go to the next item.

In my mind, I guess I don't understand how one would accomplish this ability, with out some horrible expense to performance (and yes I realize that if performance is what I am after I should not be using a `std::list`).

So how is this typically implemented?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

Comment: That table explicitly says "Yes, except erased element(s)"...

Comment: Your code is not valid, since it erases/invalidates an iterator in `list` and then (in the loop machinery) increments it and compares with `list.end()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `std::list`, the `erase()` method invalidates all references and iterators to the element(s) that have been erased.  References/iterators to other elements are not affected.

However, you are trying to increment an iterator after it has been invalidated.  That will not work, the behavior is undefined.  `erase()` returns an iterator to the next element in the list, so you need to use something more like this instead:

```
auto iter = list.begin();
while (iter != list.end())
{
    if (*iter % 2)
        iter = list.erase(iter); // or list.erase(iter++);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Or:

```
auto iter = list.begin();
while (iter != list.end())
{
    auto i = iter++;
    if (*i % 2)
        list.erase(i);
}
```

An alternative solution is to use the [`std:::list::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) method instead, let it handle the looping for you:

```
list.remove_if( [](int i){ return (i % 2); } );
```